# How to generate three and seven random digits, without repeats?

Tags: probability, random

For context, I'm trying to randomly generate phone numbers. To do this, I need to generate 999 random, non-repeating, three-digit numbers "XXX" and 9999999 random, non-repeating seven-digit numbers "YYY-YYYY." They must be generated seperately, so that phone numbers with the first three digits are grouped together.

So far, I haven't found an *efficient* way to do this. Brute forcing it (check all generated phone numbers to see if they're identical, then try again takes. . . well I couldn't be bothered to figure out what the O(n) would be because it's that bad. Binary search helps, but it could still take up to log2(9999999) (or 23) cycles each time, where each cycle involves checking half the length of the previous.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "non-repeating". Do you mean that there's no repeated digits, or that each number is distinct? (If it's the latter, it seems like you're trying to generate random permutations of the sets of 3-digit and 7-digit numbers.)

Comment: You can first generate a set of data, withour testing unicity. Then sort your set of data, from lowest to highest. Now, it is easy to detect and remove duplicates. Then, if needed, you generate missing data.

Comment: If it is a random permutation that you're looking for, then you essentially want to shuffle your data. The most obvious algorithm for this is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: You want to generate all possible phone numbers but in a random order and without repetitions, did I understand correctly? You can make a list of all possible phone numbers in numerical order, than use an algorithm to shuffle them randomly. An example of such an algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishe-Yates_shuffle

Comment: I don't think you have clearly described what your goal is. How many telephone numbers do you want? Do you want ten-digit numbers with area codes, or just seven-digit telephone numbers?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili That works. Thanks!